# "Name not defined error" when passing constants between python files

Tags: python

I have a file constants.py in which I have declared a few constant values but importing them to another file only seems to allow me to reference one of them.

In constants.py file I have declared:

```
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
FACT = 1
SCREEN_SIZE = (300,300)
```

In a game.py file I included the import statement:

```
from constants import *
```

Including these statements in the code results in "Name not defined" errors:

```
print(FACT) - doesn't work
print(SCREEN_SIZE) - works fine
print(GREEN) - doesn't work
```

I cannot understand why one works but the others don't and hoped someone could help - am sure it will be something simple!

I have tried different ways to import which hasn't fixed this:

```
import constants
from constants import *
```

Comment: Do you have `__all__` defined in `constants.py`?

Comment: Are you sure you're importing an up to date version of your module?

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new to this so not sure how I would check that?  SCREEN_SIZE was the original constant I declared and is the one that is working.  I have saved all changes I have made to the constants.py file and thought that would update with the import statement?

Comment: I do not have __all__ defined in constants.py

Answer (score 0):

Import the whole of constants.py like this:

```
import constants
```

Then refer to the values by prefixing with the library name:

```
print(constants.FACT) - works fine
print(constants.SCREEN_SIZE) - works fine
print(constants.GREEN) - works fine
```

This makes it easier for other readers to find where your constants are defined as there is a reminder at each reference.